# concatenating objects in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have an object called `teacher` and another one called `students`. I am trying to return both of them in a controller as json response, and I want the response to be like

```
{'teacher': {'first_name': 'adam', 'last_name': 'smith'}, 'students': [{'id':'5', 'age' :15}, {'id':'8', 'age' :18}]}
```

or in case of one to one relationship(one teacher has one student):

```
{'teacher': {'first_name': 'adam', 'last_name': 'smith'}, 'students':{'id':'8', 'age' :18}}
```

The point is to return a concatenated json response where one object appears inside the other one

I have tried `teacher.as_json.merge(students.as_json)`, but this does not embed the students objects inside the teacher. it just append the data

I have read in one post the `teacher['students'] = students` should work but I get always an error: `can't write unknown attribute students`

Comment: I tried the merge method, and teacher["students"] = students

Comment: the merge methods does the concatination but I still want the "students" variables inside the json file not just merging the two hashes

Comment: you need to provide more code (edit your post).

Answer (score 1):

`teacher.as_json.merge(students: (students.count > 1 ? students.as_json :  students.first.as_json ))`

Comment: Having the data structure changing when there is only one student is likely to cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: my case is just one of these not both of them. there was a small misunderstanding between the question and the answer but, this answer answers my question

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly as you would in JSON. If you have `teacher` object and `students` object, render this object:

```
{ teacher: teacher, students: students }
```

Comment: but I want the students json to be inside the teacher, with an index of "students"

Comment: That is not what your "I want the response to be something like" JSON shows. Please be precise in your questions.